# Можно ли использовать gulp-concat для объединения css файлов?

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-concat

Везде в интернете и на домашней странице плагина дается пример только на js файлах. Хотел использовать gulp-concat-css, но у него нет способа указания в каком порядке объединять файлы. А ведь это важно.
У gulp-concat такой способ есть - передать в src массив с перечислением файлов - в каком порядке перечислишь - в таком и соберет.

Попробовал на практике - работает gulp-concat для объединения css, но почему об этом нигде не говорится. Или может есть тонкости, которые на первый взгляд не видны и поэтому не стоит использовать gulp-concat для css?

Comment: Конкат не делает ничего кроме как склеивает файлы .. какие вообще тут могут быть побочные эффекты? Везде js, потому что в описании в гите привели пример с js и его все успешно копируют ... Как по мне rigger выглядит интереснее (хотя бы потому, что все пути хранятся не в gulpfile).

Comment: И да, зачем склеивать gulp'ом css'ники, когда есть препроцессоры с импортами?

Comment: препроцессоры не используются, но идея интересная, я подумаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp-concat отлично подходит для соединения файлов любого типа. Gulp-concat-css в данном случае просто не нужен, так как это лишний require.